# A homeomorphism to the open upper-half complex plane

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, quotient-group, general-linear-group

I am reading a quick course on modular forms, and I do not understand a lemma: Let $\alpha = \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d \end{pmatrix} \in SL_2(\mathbb{R}), z\in \mathbb{C}^{*}$ (the Riemann sphere), $H$ be the open upper-half complex plane and denote $\alpha(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$. I am reading a lemma that states:

The map $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})/SO_2(\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow H$ given by $\alpha \mapsto \alpha(i)$ is a homeomorphism.

I have the following questions:

$1$: Is the domain of the map meant to be $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ *quotiented* by $SO_2(\mathbb{Z})$ or $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ *set difference* $SO_2(\mathbb{Z})$? If the former is correct, can someone describe what the quotient group looks like? If the latter is correct, why do we exclude $SO_2(\mathbb{Z})$ from the domain?

$2$: Can someone give a quick proof that the map is bicontinuous? I have trouble following the proof in the notes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Out of curiosity, which course is it?

Comment: I suspect there may be an error of some sort, perhaps a typographical error. What's true is that the map $SL_2(\mathbb R) / SO_2(\mathbb R) \to H$ given by $\alpha \mapsto \alpha(i)$ is a homeomorphism. With $\mathbb Z$ instead of $\mathbb R$, this is just false.

Comment: But, anyway, the "slash" notation in this setting does *not* denote set difference, it denotes instead the *right coset space*.

Comment: As for the proof, let me suggest that rather than asking us to write a proof for you, you instead ask a mathematical question regarding how and where you get stuck when attempting to understand the proof you were given.

Comment: @StinkingBishop "Topics in Algebraic Number Theory" by A.F. Jarvis, course given at Sheffield in 2000.

Comment: @LeeMosher I see, thanks for the clarification. Can I ask what the structure of this coset space is? What are its equivalence classes? As for my request for a quick proof, you're entirely right but the proof in the notes was already deep waters for me and I did not feel confident copying it and asking for clarifications, so I thought maybe someone would happen to give a proof that would click more easily for me. Thank you anyway.

Comment: What is the topology on $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$? Set difference uses $\setminus,$ not $/.$